# Refactor Legacy SOA system to use non-blocking async microservices

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I've just started trying to get my head around RxJava so that I can use project reactor refactor Legacy SOA system to use non-blocking async microservices.

At the moment I'm do a feasibility study and looking at using something like spoon to transform the legacy service code (that has nothing to do with this question however)

I would like to know how I would use reactor-bus Request/Reply syntax to replace this synchronous service code. Or even if I should be using a completely different reactor construct.

Here is example of a legacy soa service, it is contrived so it might not make perfect sense, but basically each services is dependant on the results of the last.

```
 public static Map<String, Object> createAccount(DispatchContext dctx, Map<String, Object> context) {
    LocalDispatcher dispatcher = dctx.getDispatcher();

    String accountPartyId = (String) context.get("partyId");

    Map<String, Object> input = UtilMisc.toMap("groupName", context.get("accountName"), "groupNameLocal", context.get("groupNameLocal"), "officeSiteName", context.get("officeSiteName"), "description", context.get("description"), "partyId", accountPartyId);

    Map<String, Object> serviceResults1 = dispatcher.runSync("createPartyGroup", input);

    Map<String, Object> serviceResults2 = dispatcher.runSync("createPartyRole", UtilMisc.toMap("partyId", (String) serviceResults1.get("partyId"), "roleTypeId", "ACCOUNT"));

    String dataSourceId = (String) context.get("dataSourceId");
    Map<String, Object> serviceResults3 = null;
    if (dataSourceId != null) {
        serviceResults3 = dispatcher.runSync("crmsfa.addAccountDataSource", UtilMisc.toMap("partyId", (String) serviceResults2.get("partyId"), "dataSourceId", dataSourceId));
    }

    String marketingCampaignId = (String) context.get("marketingCampaignId");
    Map<String, Object> serviceResults4 = null;
    if (marketingCampaignId != null) {
        serviceResults4 = dispatcher.runSync("crmsfa.addAccountMarketingCampaign", UtilMisc.toMap("partyId", (String) serviceResults3.get("partyId"), "marketingCampaignId", marketingCampaignId));

    }

    String initialTeamPartyId = (String) context.get("initialTeamPartyId");
    Map<String, Object> serviceResults5 = null;
    if (initialTeamPartyId != null) {
        serviceResults5 = dispatcher.runSync("crmsfa.assignTeamToAccount", UtilMisc.toMap("accountPartyId", (String) serviceResults4.get("partyId"), "teamPartyId", initialTeamPartyId, "userLogin", userLogin));
    }

    Map<String, Object> results = ServiceUtil.returnSuccess();
    results.put("groupId", (String) serviceResults1.get("groupId"));
    results.put("roleId", (String) serviceResults2.get("roleId"));
    results.put("dataSourceId", (String) serviceResults3.get("dataSourceId"));
    results.put("marketingCampaignId", (String) serviceResults4.get("marketingCampaignId"));
    results.put("teamPartyId", (String) serviceResults5.get("teamPartyId"));
    return results;
}
```

Basically this is a service that calls other services using  dispatcher.runSync ... I'm just looking for a starting point for my research into how to possibly use reactor or even another library to transform this type of syntax into asynchronous non-blocking code.

At this point I'm thinking in very vague terms of callbacks/some sort of Promise type structure.

Like the first call to another service is

```
Map<String, Object> serviceResults = dispatcher.runSync("createPartyGroup", input);
```

If this instead returned a Promise object that contained the serviceResults map then the rest of the method could be moved into the Promise onComplete block and the result would be a deeply nested bunch of onComplete code blocks making up this service method.

```
Promise p = task {
    // createPartyGroup service call
}
p.onComplete { result ->

Promise p2 = task {
    // createPartyRole sevice call
}

p2.onComplete { result ->
//next service call
}   
}  
}
```

Or looking at reactor-bus documentation something like the following which doesn't make sense on many levels and I just don't know enough about reactor to know why it doesn't make sense or what to learn next for me to understand why it doesn't make sense

```
bus.send("service.createPartyGroup", Event.wrap(input, "reply.service.createPartyGroup")); 
bus.receive($("reply.service.createPartyGroup"), ev -> {
Map<?> input2 = UtilMisc.toMap("partyId", (String) ev.get("partyId"), "roleTypeId", "ACCOUNT")
  bus.send("service.createPartyRole", Event.wrap(input2, "reply.service.createPartyRole")); 
});
```

I realise it is a rather odd place to start researching the reactive programming paradigm. But replacing this synchronous service code is my ultimate objective and if I understood at least the syntax I can work backwards from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use Observable, where in your flow one emitted item is passed through the stream.
Check the documentation https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava

This will be a sequential flow

```
  Observable.just(methodThatCallFirstServiceAndReturnObservable(params))
            .flatMap(resul1 -> methodThatCallSecondAndReturnObservable(resul1))
            .flatMap(resul2 -> methodThatCallThirdAndReturnObservable(resul2))
            .subscribe(result3->"Last value emmited here:");
```

You can run the three service call in parallel and get all the values together using Observable.zip or merge. But I believe is not what you need here.

Comment: OK I see the general form but how do I send what was a synchronous input map as an event and how do I return the results map in the form of an event ... There is bus piping etc can you elaborate on how your code snippet relates to bus.send bus.receive or ...on() ..notify() conceptually

Comment: Sorry dont understand the question